# calculate page height within an iframe with divs in display none

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I am adding html inside an iframe, inside the html I have a div with the property display: none, which changes to block when some options are activated within the page.

The problem is that the height of the iframe is calculated with respect to the elements of the html using body.scrollHeight when loading the page. This does not count the divs that have the display: none, so at the time of changing the property to display: block, the elements appear, but the page overflows down, since the height was already calculated without having those divs.

In what way could this be solved? I can not modify the iframe, but if what goes inside.

Answer (score 0):

Try re-calculating the height of the iframe once the div becomes visible.
Also I'm not sure what youre using the iframe for, but remember that iframes are for embedding documents within a web page, if this isn't what your doing than you might find it easier to just work within the body.

Hope this at least gives you some idea of how you can fix your problem.